# Can't get Y scroll position in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, internet-explorer-9, scrolltop

I have a bit of code in my web app to call an infinite scroll fetch near the bottom of a page once the user scrolls there. It works fine in all browsers except for IE9.

```
totalHeight = $('#main-region').innerHeight()
scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
scrollPosition = 1000;
if scrollTop + scrollPosition >= totalHeight
  @fetchMethod() if @fetchMethod
```

On IE9, `$(window).scrollTop()` returns 0 no matter where I am. So does `window.pageYOffset`, `document.body.scrolltop`, and all of the other methods I've tried. Any ideas or workarounds to help me make this work on IE9?

Comment: Sorry, can't reconstruct your problem, $(window).scrollTop() is working for me in IE9.